# How can I plot a function so that it indicates undefined point?

Tags: plotting

I tried to graph a function with an undefined point. The example is as below.

```
f[x_] = (x^2 + x -6) / (-4x^2 - 16x - 12);

Plot[f[x], {x, -3.1, -2.99}]
```

The output is a curve but there should be a hole ($x$ can't be $-3$) in the curve. Is there any setting in `Plot` that will show that the curve is undefined at $x = -3$?

Comment: What's the problem?  f[-3] = -2.  Also use `:=` not `=`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) and [`ExclusionsStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html):

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -3.1, -2.99}, Exclusions -> True, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.02], Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Add in `CapForm["Round"]` for good measure.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is so helpful :)

Comment: @MiniLee I am glad it was helpful :)